# Graph of tag popularity on stats page

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics, graphs

I think it would be cool if we could see the growth of the number of question/amount of activity of various tags as a graph on the stats page.

Comment: We're one year later, does anybody know if this is already possible?

Comment: there is this [tag trends by week](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) utility from Greg Hewgill

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I also would like to see a graph for the growth of questions of various tags. E.g. right now we there is only a number of "questions tagged [tag]" on the tag page for each tag. It would be nice to have a graph that **visualize** the number, e.g. a graph for the last six months (one point per month), updated once a week. It would look something like this:

[image: Scala tag trend]

Comment: Agreed. Also I'd like to see some sort of an asymptote (?) for the number of questions on the site total. I.e. compare tag [widget] to the number of questions over time for the entire site.

Answer (score 2):

And also be able to choose to follow several tags only, say I want to compare the PHP tag versus the Phyton tag.
We can actually build an external tool for it.