# Does the acceptance rate on meta actually mean anything?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

Is there any point on showing acceptance rate on meta? While we want to encourage accepting answers if someone explains how to do something, a lot of questions such as feature requests or discussion really don't really have a correct answer to accept. Furthermore, several valid suggestions get no answers because no-one has anything else substantial to add

Comment: i think acceptance rate is meaningless on *any* of these sites.  if you're using a poster's acceptance rate as a filter for whether you should write up an answer to the question, **You're Doing It Wrong.**

Comment: @Quack: I have to disagree. I am willing to go to more effort for those who have taken the time to learn how the site works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is essentially meaningless. (Look at mine!)

Because Meta is primarily focused on discussion, it is unlikely that most questions qualify for even having best answers.

Comment: I never look at acceptance rates on meta because questions don't always have a definitive answer. However, I tend to mark an answer as accepted because others do consider the acceptance rate important.

Answer (score 2):

I think its important.

Say you ask for a feature request and it gets denied, you still have an answer (you might not like the answer) but an answer still.

I think if you are asking for a feature request, but no one has anything to add, then perhaps it is either not a good suggestion, or it needs to be thought out a little more?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't officially reply to every suggestion. Besides: I think that this is a [good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49084/graph-of-tag-popularity-on-stats-page) despite no answers