# Graph trends for activity within tags

Tags: feature-request

I'd love to see graphs of the activity on a tag shown on the tag's page.  A lot like what Greg Hewgill did here using the data dump:

[Tag trends by week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23554/tag-trends-by-week/105690)

It would be great to see new activity trends and cumulative activity trends since the latter is easier to read for relatively low-activity topics.

Comment: What sort of behavior would you like to encourage by doing this?

Comment: I see this feature making SO a more useful site, hopefully without altering people's behavior.  Activity trends say a lot about the health of technologies and their communities.  On the down side, it might encourage gaming the site to make your favorite tech appear more active.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49084/graph-of-tag-popularity-on-stats-page/95203#95203

Comment: Was looking for this, as I wanted to see how [wp7] was doing against the competition over time.

Comment: Greg's site is a nice start, but it's harder to use for newer tags.  For example comparing two frameworks only a few months old for activity.  There are many improvements that would be worthwhile for the community for a number of purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a table not a graph, but is does give precise comparison of tag activity over the last 6 months.

Enter two tags and you'll see their mass and momentum and monthly growth:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90306